# Python should I close the file after reading

Tags: python, django, file

I'm using Django 1.10 and Python 3.5.3

In one of the views the user is sending a file and I'm reading it like that:

```
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        file_serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        file_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        if file_serializer.is_valid():
            if 'file' in request.data:

                # hash file
                hasher = hashlib.md5()
                read_file = request.data['file'].read()
                hasher.update(read_file)
                current_file_hash = hasher.hexdigest()
```

My question is - Should I close the file afterwards? Seems like I don't actually open it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, `request.data['file']` is actually an open file descriptor, not a filename. If you know `request` will take care of cleaning up its own resources, there's obviously no need to explicitly close the file. Otherwise, close it with `request.data['file'].close()`. In that case, it would be best to wrap the entire function body in a `try` / `finally`-block, to assure the file gets closed no matter what:

```
try:
    # read from file etc.
finally:
    request.data['file'].close()
```